# Be $X$ a topological space and $D_1$, $D_2 \subseteq X$ dense in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Be $X$ a topological space and $D_1$, $D_2 \subseteq X$ dense in $X$. Can it be said that $D_1 \cap D_2$ is dense in $X$? And if $D_1$, besides dense, is also open in $X$.

If $D_1$ is dense in $X$ this means that $\overline{D_1}=X$. In the same way that $D_2$ is dense in $X$ this means that $\overline{D_2}=X$, so the intersection is also dense in X.

Is that correct? Can someone help me please?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are both dense in $\Bbb R$, but they are disjoint.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you!!!! Do you help me in the other questions I posted about topology?

Comment: If $D_1$ is open as well as dense in $X$, consider let $U$ be any non-empty open set. Then $U\cap D_1$ is a non-empty open set, and $D_2$ is dense in $X$, so ... ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So the intersection is dense in $X$, so if $D_1$ is opened?

Comment: Yes: if $D_1$ is open, the intersection is dense in $X$.

Comment: That's good!!!!

Answer (score 1):

What about $X= \mathbb R$, $D_1 = \mathbb Q$ and $D_2= \mathbb R \setminus Q$?

... Where $D_1 \cap D_2 = \emptyset$.